# DirectX errors Vector3

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

Im using directxtutorial.com tutorial.. Im getting errors in these lines :

```
D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
&D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 8.0f, 25.0f),    // the camera position //error
&D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),      // the look-at position //error
&D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));    // the up direction //error
```

c++\test 1\test1\main.cpp|145|error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]

In all three of them. What do they mean and how can i fix them? I was googling for answers, but none has those errors in these lines. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing to the `D3DXMatrixLookAtLH()` function the address of *temporary* `D3DXVECTOR3` objects.
Instead, try building these instances of `D3DXVECTOR3` on the stack, and pass their addresses, e.g.:

```
D3DXVECTOR3 cameraPos(0.0f, 8.0f, 25.0f);
D3DXVECTOR3 lookAtPos(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
D3DXVECTOR3 upDir(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
// Assume that you have properly defined matView

D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(
  &matView,
  &cameraPos,
  &lookAtPos,
  &upDir);
```